# File is in Use VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file, scanning, twain

I am using VB.NET (VS-2012), I use to scan documents in my applicant software. When i scan document i resize the scanned image and save it over the original file. When the user scan all the required documents then the use click the save button. After clicking the save button the application upload the images to database and try to delete the locally created files but stuck with the error that the file is in use.
I am using the following code...

```
Tw.Init(Me.Handle)
If (Not msgfilter) Then
  Me.Enabled = False
  msgfilter = True
  Application.AddMessageFilter(Me)
End If

If SelectScanner Then
  Tw.Select()
  SelectScanner = False
End If
```

Tw.Acquire(chkScanner.Checked)

This function listens the event triggered by tw.acquire()

```
Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean Implements IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
Try
  Dim cmd As TwainCommand = Tw.PassMessage(m)
  If (cmd = TwainCommand.Not) Then
    Return False
  End If

  Select Case cmd
    Case TwainCommand.CloseRequest
      EndingScan()
      Tw.CloseSrc()
    Case TwainCommand.CloseOk
      EndingScan()
      Tw.CloseSrc()
    Case TwainCommand.DeviceEvent
    Case TwainCommand.TransferReady
      Dim pics As ArrayList = Tw.TransferPictures()

      EndingScan()
      Tw.CloseSrc()
      For i = 0 To pics.Count - 1 Step 1
        flName = TempPath & "\" & GetNextFileName(TempPath, lstDocType.Items(cboDocTypes.SelectedIndex).ToString)
        Dim img As IntPtr = CType(pics(i), IntPtr)
        SaveImage(img)

        lstDocuments.Items.Add(flName)
        lstDocType.Items.Add(GetDocType(cboDocTypes.SelectedIndex))
        SetItemData(lstDocuments, lstDocuments.Items.Count - 1, GetItemData(lstApplicants, lstApplicants.SelectedIndex))

        Try
          lstDocuments.SelectedIndex = lstDocuments.Items.Count - 1
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Dim Original As Image = Image.FromFile(flName)
        Dim Resized As Image = ResizeImage(Original, New Size(1024, 1407), False)
        Original.Dispose()
        Resized.Save(flName, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        Resized.Dispose()
        img = Nothing
        pics = Nothing
      Next
      Tw.Dispose()
    Case 0
      Return False
    End Select
    Return True
  Catch ex As Exception
    Return False
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
  End Try
End Function
```

In this given function you can see that the image is resized and the original image is replaced with the resized one. And then the resize object is disposed but when the software try to delete the image after uploading it to database, an error occurs.

I don't know whats the problem.

Comment: In which line does the exception rise? and what is the error message / inner exception?

Comment: When Resized.Save(flName, ImageFormat.Jpeg) line is executed then the file is saved to disk. after the scanning process is completed i use the following code to copy the file to another location and delete the file, then the exception is raised.

Comment: In which LINE exactly? and the error message is...? Image.Dispose() doesn't delete the file, where are you supposed to be doing that?